# @Transactional annotation does not rollback

Tags: spring, postgresql, jdbc, transactions, spring-jdbc

I struggle to get `@Transactional` to work in combination with `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate()` in an enterprise application. It was hard to debug, so I built a working minimal example in Spring Boot just to check my approach. In the minimal example I use Spring Boot 2.4.0 with the H2 Database.

This is the `DatabaseContext`:

```java
@Configuration
public class DatabaseContext {

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedDatabase embeddedDatabase() {
        EmbeddedDatabase db = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .addScript("import.sql")
                .build();
        return db;
    }

    @Bean
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate(EmbeddedDatabase embeddedDatabase) {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(embeddedDatabase);
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager txManager(EmbeddedDatabase embeddedDatabase) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(embeddedDatabase);
    }
}
```

This is the repository of the minimal example:

```java
@Repository
public class TransactionalRepositoryImpl implements TransactionalRepository {
    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<TransactionalEntity> store(List<TransactionalEntity> entities) {
        String insertSql = "insert into entities "
                + "      ( "
                + "         firstName, "
                + "         lastName "
                + "    ) "
                + "  values" + "      ("
                + "          :firstName, "
                + "          :lastName "
                + "    ) ";

        List<MapSqlParameterSource> batchOfInserts = new ArrayList<>();
        for (TransactionalEntity entity : entities) {
            MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
            params.addValue("firstName", entity.getFirstName());
            params.addValue("lastName", entity.getLastName());
            batchOfInserts.add(params);
        }

        int[] insertCounts = new int[0];


        if (batchOfInserts.size() > 0) {
            insertCounts = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(insertSql, batchOfInserts.toArray(new MapSqlParameterSource[0]));
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(insertCounts));

        return entities;
    }
}
```

I call the repository like this:

```java
TransactionalEntity entity1 = new TransactionalEntity("Foo", "Bar");
TransactionalEntity entity2 = new TransactionalEntity("Foo", "Bar");
//TransactionalEntity entity2 = new TransactionalEntity("Zoo", "Car");
transactionalRepository.store(ImmutableList.of(entity1, entity2));
```

This should fail with `DuplicateKeyException` for `entity2`, as there is a primary key in H2 that prevents inserts with the same values more than once. It does fail for `entity2`, and because of the `@Transactional` annotation, also `entity1` is not in H2 afterwards. If I then remove `@Transactional` from the repository, the same exception is thrown, but `entity1` is in H2. So far so good, this is exactly as expected.

Now to my actual enterprise application. It is a big monolithic multi-module Spring app (not Spring Boot). Instead of H2, it uses Postgres. It is naturally much more complex than my minimal example. However a few key things are actually pretty much the same. The repository setup is basically identical to my minimal example, and so is the `DatabaseContext` (it uses `DataSource` instead of `EmbeddedDatabase` though). The context is imported into another `@Configuration` class using `@Import`. That class is annotated with `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` and has a `@ComponentScan` that covers the repository. It itself is imported by a third `@Configuration` class `public class WebApplicationConfig extends DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration`.

When I now trigger an action similar to my minimal example, causing a `DuplicateKeyException`, I find that the first of the two values still has been inserted into the database despite the `@Transactional` annotation, which of course is *not* as expected.

I played around with a few things. I annotated the context with `@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)`. I even tried to get the transaction working programmatically instead, using

```java
@Bean
public TransactionTemplate txTemplate(PlatformTransactionManager txManager){
    return new TransactionTemplate(txManager);
}
```

without success.

I am just a bit out of ideas how to debug this any further, so I am hoping for input here. Thank you :)

Comment: How do you call the store() method in your actual application where transaction is not working? Is that an internal method call for any reason ? Sharing the actual code with relevant bits would help understand the issue better .

Comment: How do you define an internal call? It's an API call, but with a few business logic layers in-between

Comment: Is `store()` called from another method within the same bean is the question?

Comment: Yes, though that one is annotated with @Transactional as well.

Comment: It would be better if you could share the relevant bits of the actual code . Otherwise one can speculate only . What I am trying to understand is that , is there a txn started and are these inserts happening within the context of that single txn.

Comment: I can't share the original code unfortunately as it's proprietary. I tried to make an obfuscated version of it in my minimal example, but I totally see why that might not be enough context. I am just not sure how else to share it. I will have another look at the original code later and try to see if there is anything important that I have missed. In the meantime I would be thankful for hints as to how I can debug this, i.e. how I can maybe make the existing contexts more visible and how I can see in which one the transaction is or isn't running in.

Comment: You may use [TransactionSynchronizationManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronizationManager.html) and log the required transaction details

Comment: Thanks, yeah so I get this: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction synchronization is not active`.

Comment: From the api documentation shared please check the section starting with -“Resource management code should only “ . Either txn is not active or synchronisation is not supported . Make sure it is not the first reason

Comment: "isSynchronizationActive();" returns `false`

Comment: So, I just made it work, but I don't understand why. I basically have dedicated Maven modules for controller, service, and repository layers. So far I was working only in the repository module. Now I wanted to test if `@Transactional` worked on the service layer. I used it on a method that calls another non-transactional method that calls the repository method on which I couldn't make `@Transactional` work. And not only did it work on that service method, all of a sudden it was also active on the repository layer. So while I am very happy it works, I don't quite understand why :/ Do you?

Comment: Without seeing the code I can only speculate. Only thing for sure is there was no transaction initialised earlier when you faced issue

Comment: Well, to provide some kind of closure, while it worked when called from another method that was annotated with `Transactional`, it continued to not work if that wasn't the case. I ended up doing it programmatically with `TransactionTemplate`, which works. I assume `Transactional` not working has something to do with AspectJ and AOP, but really not sure.